# Build a DataTable from scratch using F#

Tags: f#

Is it possible to build a DataTable object from scratch using F#

I have written this code

```
module DataHelper
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.SqlClient

let addDataRow (dt : DataTable) kerberos =
    let dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr["Kerberos"] = kerberos
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

let Func userList : string seq = 
    let dt : DataTable = new DataTable("UserNameListType")
    let dc : DataColumn = new DataColumn("Kerberos")
    dt.Columns.Add(dc)
    Seq.iter (fun user -> addDataRow dt user) userList
    dt
```

But this has too many errors

1. VS.NET does not seem to understand DataTable, DataRow classes and only shows me a "Note" as intellisense.
2. Its hard to use the collection objects Rows, Columns in F# because none of the methods really work (which work easily in C#).

Comment: Have you added the correct references? - if you mouse over the `Note` it should say what is missing.  I don't understand what you mean by `None of the methods work` - you will need to be more specific

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're doing this in a new project, you need to add references to `System.Data.dll` and `System.Xml.dll`. After that, Visual Studio should recognize the types. You can do that by right clicking on "References" in your project and choosing "Add Reference".

Aside from that, there are two minor mistakes in your code. The assignment should be written as (note that there is a dot before `[` and the operator is `<-` instead of `=`):

```
dr.["Kerberos"] <- kerberos
```

And your `Func` function should return `DataTable`:

```
let Func userList : DataTable =
```